# save calculator result and show them as a list using SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, calculator, history

i have successfully implemented a calculator with a history activity in which it will show old results in a list view 
but i am facing a problem that the first line is always null

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJIV8.jpg

i tried to make default string " Old Calculation "

```
>    String w = "Old Calculation";
```

but this didn't work,
my app save the result in a multiline String in SharedPreferences and pass it to another activity through an intent

```
>SharedPreferences.Editor editor ; // saving shared preferences editor as MainAcitivty class attribute
```

under the onCreate i set the String value to sharedpref

```
> SharedPreferences prefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        w = prefs.getString("saved", null);
```

update method in which i update the result string value with the String s( String s is the calculated result)

```
>     public void update(String s){
        editor= getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        w =     w
                + System.getProperty ("line.separator")
                + s
                + System.getProperty ("line.separator");
        editor.putString("saved", w);
        editor.apply();
    }
```

Passing W value to the activity in which i will show the result in TextView list

```
>    public void History(View v){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, History.class);
        myIntent.putExtra("message", w);
        startActivity(myIntent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_slide_in_left, 
        R.anim.anim_slide_out_left);
    }
```

History activity

```
    public class History extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView tv1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_history);
        String w ="Old calculation is showed here";
        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        print(w);
    }

    public void print(String w) {
            Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
            w = bundle.getString("message");

            tv1.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

            tv1.setText(w);

    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.anim_slide_in_right, R.anim.anim_slide_out_right);
    }
    public void deleteAppData(View v) {
        try {
            // clearing app data
            String packageName = getApplicationContext().getPackageName();
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            runtime.exec("pm clear "+packageName);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you store data from activity *A* and you want  retrieve it from another activity, You must use `SharedPreferences` as below:

`SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(String, int);`

`String` is FileName like *"result"*
`int` is Mode like *MODE_PRIVATE*
for example see [this link](http://androidopentutorials.com/android-sharedpreferences-tutorial-and-example/)

in addition i [wrote a simple code](https://beepaste.io/view/pNJXHV) for help you